# Appium Testing for charging and discharging of battery in android phones?

Tags: appium, batterylevel

It is possible to test Power charging and discharging in android phones using appium tool or we can go with other tool.?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with appium 1.6 you can get device performance data:

```
List<String> dataTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
dataTypes.add("cpuinfo");
dataTypes.add("memoryinfo");
dataTypes.add("batteryinfo");
dataTypes.add("networkinfo");
// check what data type you can get
List<String> supportedPerformanceDataTypes =driver.
  getSupportedPerformanceDataTypes();
// get data
List<List<Object>> performanceData =driver.
  getPerformanceData("your.app.package", "dataType", dataReadTimeout);
```

For more details go to appium [repository](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/024d7ac7bb5ff1216e081ab76954163aeff7da30/docs/en/commands/device/performance-data/performance-data-types.md)

So with Appium you can only get battery status and check if its changing.

Comment: I'm getting error when i running this code..Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: That URL did not map to a valid JSONWP resource..

Comment: Now we solved the error.But we are not getting any information.just its returning the response like [cpuinfo, memoryinfo, batteryinfo, networkinfo].

Comment: Thanks for the information now i can get the information of battery.  I'm using the driver.getSupportedPerformanceData() method.

Comment: Glad you finally get it. Good luck with your tests!

Comment: How we can get a IMEI number of the device..Is there any method for that.